# Синонимичные определения в терминах или в словарной статье

Tags: пунктуация

В академических текстах зачастую последовательно указываются несколько синонимичных терминов для одного понятия (причём второй и последующие обычно выделяются курсивом), однако зачастую авторы не придерживаются единого пунктуационного оформления. Какие варианты можно считать правомерными?

1. Определение, или *дефиниция*, — ...
2. Определение или *дефиниция* — ...
3. ... — это называется определением или *дефиницией*, однако ...
4. ... — это называется определением, или *дефиницией*, однако ...
5. ... — это называется определением (или *дефиницией*), однако ...
6. ... — это называется определением (или *дефиницией*, или *объяснением*), однако ...
7. ... — это называется определением, или *дефиницией*, или *объяснением*, однако ...
8. ... — это называется определением или *дефиницией* и зачастую *объяснением* ...
9. ... — это называется определением, или *дефиницией*, и зачастую *объяснением* ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Общие пояснения к решению**

1. В каждом случае надо учитывать **вид союза ИЛИ** (разделительный или пояснительный) и **его структуру** (одиночный или повторяющийся). Запятая **не ставится,** если союз ИЛИ разделительный и одиночный, но **ставится**, если союз ИЛИ пояснительный, а также если он повторяющийся.
2. **Пояснительным** союз ИЛИ будет в том случае, если он **употребляется** в тексте в качестве **добавочного пояснения**. В этом случае он обособляется запятой, также для обособления можно использовать скобки.
3. **Разделительным** он будет, если он участвует **в построении текста**, где говорится о двух возможных названиях, и тогда в предложении используется **глагол "называется".**
4. **Скобки** можно использовать для обоих видов союзов; внутри скобок запятые ставятся по своим правилам, без учета вида предложения. На постановку остальных знаков скобки не оказывают влияния.

**Решение**

1. Определение, или дефиниция, — ... пояснение, верный вариант
2. Определение или дефиниция — ... неверный вариант
3. ... — это называется определением или дефиницией, однако ... разделительный союз, верный вариант
4. ... — это называется определением, или дефиницией, однако ... неверный вариант
5. ... — это называется определением (или дефиницией), однако ...верный вариант
6. ... — это называется определением (или дефиницией, или объяснением), однако ... повторяющийся союз, верный вариант
7. ... — это называется определением, или дефиницией, или объяснением, однако ...повторяющийся союз со второго однородного члена, верный вариант
8. ... — это называется /определением или дефиницией/ и зачастую объяснением ... верный вариант, здесь комбинация союзов, поэтому оба союза (ИЛИ, И) считаются одиночными.
9. ... — это называется определением, или дефиницией, и зачастую объяснением ... неверный вариант или скорее нежелательный вариант, так как роль союзов неясна.

Comment: Замечательный ответ, спасибо!